# Rails crushlovely / mobiscroll-rails installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails app, I added:

```
gem 'mobiscroll-rails'
```

I ran $ bundle install

But, I don't think any of the mobiscroll files got loaded into my app.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to add `//= require mobiscroll` to your `application.js`, and `*= require mobiscroll` to your `application.css`.

Comment: I looked at the gem source, and it's not located within your project, but within the gem itself. You can do `bundle open mobiscroll-rails` to find it.